# Ember.js - I want an Action event (on="") to trigger when there is a transition to a new Route

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, action

I want an Action event (on="") to trigger when there is a transition to a new Route.

I've seen the list of Action event handlers and closest I could find is attaching the action to the largest HTML element on the page and triggering it with 'Mousemove". This is a terribly flawed away of going about what I want to do.

So just to draw it out.

```
<div {{action 'displayEitherHtml1or2'}} class="largestDOMelement">
  {{#if showHtml1}}
   // html 1 inside
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showHtml2}}
  // html 2 inside
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

'/objects' is a list of objects and clicking one leads to 'object/somenumber'. The action should automatically trigger when I enter the 'object/somenumber' page.

UPDATE: I've taken the contents from the previous update and dumped them into my DocRoute, but nothing it being triggered when I transition to 'doc' through {{#link-to 'doc' this.docID}} {{docTitle}}{{/link-to}}

```
VpcYeoman.DocRoute = Ember.Route.extend(VpcYeoman.Authenticated,{
    toggleLetterSwitch: false,
    togglePermitSwitch: false,
    activate: function () {  
      var docTemplateID = this.get('docTemplateID');
      if ( docTemplateID == 2) {
        this.set('toggleLetterSwitch', true);
        this.set('togglePermitSwitch', false);
        console.log('docTemplateID equals 2');
      } else {
        this.set('toggleLetterSwitch', false);
        this.set('togglePermitSwitch', true);
      }        
    }
});
```

UPDATE DOS: setDocID is set in the DocsController to 1. Here's the whole thing.

```
VpcYeoman.DocsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
  tempDocId: 1, 
  actions: {
    addDoc: function (params) {
      var docTitle = this.get('docTitle');
      var docTemplateID = 1;
      var docTemplateID = this.get('tempDocId');
      console.log(this.get('tempDocId'));
      var store = this.store;
      var current_object = this;
      var doc = current_object.store.createRecord('doc', {
        docTitle:docTitle,
        docTemplateID:docTemplateID
      });
      doc.save();
      return true;
    },
    setDocId: function (param) {
      this.set('tempDocId', param);
      console.log(this.get('tempDocId'))
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: if you check here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L486 there's an 'activate' hook, you can override that in your route, it will be fired when a route is activated. There are many hooks you can use in the routes like 'beforeModel', 'afterModel', etc. In that file you can find them all. Hope that helps.

Comment: This has helped a lot and so has pjmorse's advice on the 'active hook'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fanta commented, it seems like you're looking for [the `activate` hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate) within your Route. This gets called when you enter the route where you define it. If you want to call it on every transition, you might consider defining a base route for your application and extending that instead of Em.Route:

```
App.BaseRoute = Em.Route.extend(
    activate: function () {
        // Do your thing
    }
);
App.YourRoutes = App.BaseRoute.extend()
```

It's possible that there's a more appropriate place/time to do this, but without knowing quite what your action does, this is probably the best guess.

ETA: Looking at your edit, you won't want all your routes to extend App.BaseRoute the way I did it above; you should probably just include that `activate` hook explicitly in the routes which need it.

Comment: I've updated my OP with the exact going-ons of the action i want to use. Should I just place the contents of action 'displayEitherHtml1or2' and then delete 'displayEitherHtml1or2' our of DocController. I have a normal DocRoute & DocsRoute. I'll only be using this once so perhaps a BaseRoute is not necessary

Comment: Yes, that's right - you'd remove the action and put the body of it inside the `activate` hook where I put the `// Do your thing` comment. If you had some reason to keep it as an action (and I don't see why, but it's possible) you'd bring up the Controller from the Route and do `controller.send('displayEitherHtml1or2')` but that's contorted enough that I wouldn't do it if I didn't need to.

Comment: So the addition of active{} will be in the DocRoute and not the plural DocsRoute?

Comment: In addition to the contents of 'displayEitherHtml1or2' being added to the DocRoute, should I place 'toggleLetterSwitch: false' & 
  'togglePermitSwitch: false'  above 'active'?

Comment: Yes, the DocRoute not the DocsRoute; it will run when you enter the route. And yes, put the attributes in there too, unless you want them to be undefined at first.

Comment: Am I missing something? I have updated the question to include the active hook. I added console.log's after the 'if' and 'else' to notify me if they are triggering. I've discovered that only the 'else' is triggering to console.log, but the HTML is not toggling.

Comment: I used console.log(this.get('togglePermitSwitch')); after the 'else' statement to make sure that the values of the Switches were being toggled. They are so says the console. Still, the HTML is not toggling.

Comment: This is a different question, then: is `docTemplateId` set to anything when the `activate` hook is called? If not, why not? (It might be because `activate` is called before `docTemplateId` is set, in which case you have a choice of finding that value elsewhere or using a different hook.)

Comment: I dont think this is a different question because the action that loads the new scripts should toggle the HTML by default when it reverts to 'else' after not receiving a number value.

Comment: No, that is a different question. Your original question was how to trigger an action on transition to a new route. We've answered that. Your new question is why your HTML does not toggle when the value changes.